# If the RMI heading rose is stuck, would the needle still display correct bearing?

Tags: flight-instruments, radio-navigation

If the RMI (Radio Magnetic Indicator) heading rose gets stuck, would the RMI needle still display correct QDM (magnetic bearing to station)?

Comment: Define what you mean by “correct”?  How would you read the needle? Is the question “Does it ***display*** correctly” or “Can the correct information still be derived?”

Comment: @Jim: can the correct information about QDM be derived?

Comment: @SachinChaudhary Please always **edit** your question to include all information when asked for clarification. People shouldn't have to read through the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 4):

It would be like a "Fixed Card" ADF (old style indicator).

If your actual magnetic heading was 040 degrees but the heading rose was stuck indicating a magnetic heading of 280 degrees and the RMI needle was pointing at 330 degrees on the heading rose, then the "relative" (correct) bearing to the station would be 50 degrees to the  right.

So, with a bit of arithmetic (actual magnetic heading of 40 degrees + relatve bearing to the station of 50 degrees) the derived magnetic bearing to the station would be 90 degrees.

RMIs typically have 2 bearing pointers (for example, one for ADF  and one for VOR) but the "relative" bearing principle would be the same.

Comment: But the QDM information is already contained in the VOR signal, so the receiver actually knows the value of "QDM" when the signals are received. So wouldn't the RMI nose simply point to that known QDM value? Since it's pre known from the VOR signal.

Comment: @SachinChaudhary I don't think so. The RMI needle would simply point to the VOR station (just like pointing to an NDB). If the Dictional Gyro (DG) was stuck the needle would just rotate until it was pointing to the VOR. Similar with respect to an HSI (earlier question) the RMI is two separate nav components in the same container.  They are not making integrated and coordinated calculations just combing two separate overlaying functions in the same display.  (Although, other functions like using a heading bug to command the autopilot, etc. is possible). The RMI is not that sophisticated.