# Is QDM displayed wrong for the VOR in the aircraft?

Tags: navigation, vor, radio-navigation, great-circle

Clearly, the VOR signals follow a great circle track. Since, they follow great circle tracks, the track to the station, measured at the aircraft (either, true or magnetic), would be different due to convergency. But the QDM display doesn't take account the earth convergency, it is simply reciprocal of the QDR. So isn't the information displayed slightly incorrect?

Or, is QDM supposed to be a rhumb line track to the vor? in that case we need to apply conversion angle .

SO QDM = QDR +/- 180 would turn out to be wrong right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is QDR = QDM ± 180 always true in the case of an NDB?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90561/is-qdr-qdm-%c2%b1-180-always-true-in-the-case-of-an-ndb)

Comment: no, that is in a different context

Comment: How so?  (besides NDB vs VOR, the answer is the same, no?)

Comment: @MichaelHall closing questions based on the _answer_ being the same is a bit problematic. They are similar questions though, I agree.

Comment: @Jamiec, Beyond a vague similarity, the fundamental concept behind the two questions appears identical.  If the OP was responsive and could clarify their confusion over possible perceived differences I would be understanding.  Otherwise, should we expect another question about the effects of earth curvature on TACAN bearings a year from now?

Comment: @MichaelHall I take your point entirely. I'll reserve VtC but if someone else does i'll not object at all.

Comment: Maybe we should edit the first question to be more broad and cover any ground based navaid?

Answer (score 3):

While you're technically right, that VOR radials are great circles, the effective range of a VOR makes the difference from magnetic whilst tracking a radial irrelevant.

So, *for all practical purposes*, QDM does indeed equal QDR +/- 180 degrees.

Comment: Thank you. Also, Is QDM "supposed" to be the magnetic "rhumb" line track to the station,
or is it supposed to be the magnetic "great circle" track to the station?

Comment: @SachinChaudhary Great circle